# Какая частица (НЕ или НИ) должна быть использована в данном тексте?

Tags: не-или-ни

Не хватает не злости,
Не нежности –
Не хватает в судьбе безмятежности...

Какая частица должна быть использована в этих строках - НЕ или НИ?

Answer (score 4):

Всё зависит от смысла высказывания.

Если в предложении задумано отрицание при однородных ЗЛОСТИ, НЕЖНОСТИ и предполагается утверждение БЕЗМЯТЕЖНОСТИ, тогда пишется НЕ, ср.:

***Не хватает не злости, Не нежности -  (а) Не хватает в судьбе безмятежности.*** Злость и нежность отрицаются, утверждается безмятежность.

Другое дело, если существительные ЗЛОСТИ, НЕЖНОСТИ, БЕЗМЯТЕЖНОСТИ - однородные в том смысле, что не хватает  и того, и другого, и третьего. Тогда пишем сочинительный союз НИ..., НИ... при однородных членах: НИ ЗЛОСТИ, НИ НЕЖНОСТИ.

Comment: _**Другое дело, если существительные ЗЛОСТИ, НЕЖНОСТИ, БЕЗМЯТЕЖНОСТИ - однородные в том смысле, что не хватает и того, и другого, и третьего.  Тогда пишем сочинительный союз НИ..., НИ... при однородных членах: НИ ЗЛОСТИ, НИ НЕЖНОСТИ.**_ === Всё так. Только тогда вместо _противопоставительного_ тире, скорее всего, стояла бы запятая (или точка, или многоточие...): _Не хватает НИ злости, НИ нежности(,) не хватает в судьбе безмятежности_...

Comment: Вы правы, согласна. При существующих знаках НЕ при однородных членах наиболее вероятно.

Answer (score 0):

**Не хватает не злости, Не нежности — Не хватает в судьбе безмятежности..**.

О том, что здесь пишется отрицательная частица НЕ, можно догадаться не только по знаку тире, **но и по смыслу.**

Злость и нежность — в данном случае антонимы,  определяющие крайние границы эмоционального состояния, поэтому безмятежность может быть им **только противопоставлена.**

Answer (score -1):

НЕ хватает НИ злости, НИ нежности – НЕ хватает в судьбе безмятежности...

> Повторяющаяся частица ни приобретает значение союза, например:
>
> Нигде не было видно ни воды, ни деревьев (Чехов).
>
> Ни музы, ни труды, ни радости досуга — ничто не заменит единственного
>   друга (Пушкин).
>
> Но толпы бегут, не замечая ни его, ни его тоски (Чехов).
>
> Я не знаю ни кто вы, ни кто он (Тургенев).

[Источник](http://therules.ru/vowels-13/).